# Can the product of two non-compact spaces be compact?

Tags: general-topology

Tychonoff's theorem states that the product of two compact spaces is compact. But, is it possible for two spaces to both not be compact, yet have a product which is compact?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are *nonempty* spaces such that $X\times Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact since the projection $X\times Y\to X$ is continuous and surjective.

Comment: Amusingly, if the axiom of choice fails we will have an infinite collection of non-compact spaces whose product is empty, so a fortiori compact. So "The arbitrary product of noncompact spaces is noncompact" is, stupidly, equivalent to the axiom of choice.